# zend server - php version upgrade

Tags: php, zend-server-ce

What is the best approach to upgrade from Zend Server CE 5.0 with php 5.2 to Zend Server CE 5.1 with php 5.3?

Uninstall and reinstall?
Install over existing version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the existing setup itself you can upgrade Zend Server CE to higher versions. This can save your configuration time if you are having lot of configuration in your existing server

Check Page: 69 in the following pdf -

http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Server-CE-Installation-Guide-V40-n.pdf

You can upgrade Zend Server CE to Zend Server as well.

Comment: I upgraded like this and it was a very straight forward process with minimal downtime:
`# ./upgrade_zs_php.sh 5.3 ce`



Running this script preformed the following:
* Configures your package manager to use Zend Server repository
* Removes the previous Zend Server installation if it exists
* Installs Zend Server PHP 5.3 on your system using your package manager
* Restores old configuration files

Comment: Thank you :). Worked perfect for Windows 8/Zend CE Server for Php 5.3 to 5.4 upgrade

Comment: It appears that the link is broken.